# View in the cart the product's regular price plus the custom options selected for each product added

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, shopping-cart, cart

Is it possible to view inside a column in the cart, the regular price plus the custom options selected for each product added? (the cost should vary depending on the quantity of the product and the options selected)

Which code should I edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to edit the row on the cart page. For that have a look on the default.phtml file in "template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml".

Hope this will help.